# importing main_agent python module

Tags: python-3.x, reinforcement-learning

I am trying to run a Python code for reinforcement learning that imports a module named main_agent. I wonder if I can get access either to the source code or to import such a module.

```sh
pip install main_agent
```

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement main_agent (from versions: none)
>   ERROR: No matching distribution found for main_agent

Comment: Could you give more information about the code? Are you trying to use some open source implementation of any algorithm?

Comment: I don't think `main_agent` is a pip package. Would you like to provide more info such as where `main_agent` is mentioned in your code or could you provide the `tree` structure of your code?